# RabbitMQ queue messages

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

At the rabbitMQ web interface at the queue tab I see "Overview" panel where I found these:

Queued messages :

- Ready
- Unacknowledged
- Total

I guess what is the "Total" messages. But what is "Ready" and  "Unacknowledged" ?
"Ready" - messages that were delivered to the consumer?
"Unacknowledged" - ?

Message rates:

- Publish
- Deliver
- Redelivered
- Acknowledge

And what are these messages? Especially "Redelivered" and "Acknowledge"? What does this mean?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Ready**
Is the number of messages that are available to be delivered.

**Unacknowledged**
Is the number of messages for which the server is waiting for acknowledgement(If a client recieved the message but dont send a acknowledge yet).

**Total**
Is the sum of Ready and Unacknowledged messages.

About your second question:

**Publish**
This is the rate how many messages are incomming to the RabbitMQ server.

**Deliver**
This is the rate at which messages requiring acknowledgement are being delivered in response to basic.consume.

**Acknowledge**
Rate at which messages are being acknowledged by the client/consumer.

**Redelivered**
Rate at which messages with the 'redelivered' flag set are being delivered. For example if you dont got a acknowledge message for a delivered message, you will deliver this message again.

Comment: This is almost the same as in the help dialog. @Rene can you clarify what the 'ready' number means? In my case I see that number increasing, but it never comes back down again, it just flatttens out after we have priocessed some tasks. Everything seems to function like expected, bet the graph just repeatedly goes up and flattens out.

Comment: @RicoSuave "ready" means how many messages are inside your queue. Small Example: If you push 100 messages to the queue, the size of total and ready will be 100. If you consume(without acknowledge) 20 messages from this queue you have 80 messages ready, 20 messages unacknowledged and 100 messages in total. If you acknowledge now from this 20 consumed messages just 10, then the other 10 messages will be again ready after a given time. This means you have now 90 ready and 90 in total. 
Your case sounds for me that you publish faster messages to the queue then consuming them.